# Putting the contents of a multidimentional array into a ListView with a for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listview, for-loop

I have the following variables and array. I'm trying to push the values into a ListView to display them.

```
        int oneLIAR = 0;
        int twoLIAR = 0;
        int threeLIAR = 0;
        int fourLIAR = 0;
        int fiveLIAR = 0;
        int sixLIAR = 0;
        int sevenLIAR = 0;
        int eightLIAR = 0;
        int nineLIAR = 0;
        int tenplusLIAR = 0;
        string[,] rowsViewLossCount = new string[10, 2] {
            {"1", oneLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"2", twoLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"3", threeLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"4", fourLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"5", fiveLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"6", sixLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"7", sevenLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"8", eightLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"9", nineLIAR.ToString("#,##0")},
            {"10+", tenplusLIAR.ToString("#,##0")}
        };
```

When I try the following loop, I get an error:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (rowsViewLossCount.Length-1); i++)
        {
            listViewLossCount.Items.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 0]).SubItems.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 1]);
        }
```

I get the error "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled", "Index was outside the bounds of the array." At the time of the error, i = 10, which means it is out of bounds because it should only ever get to 9. But, I tried replacing in my for loop as "i < 5" to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: .Length returns the total number of elements in the array (in your case its 10 * 2 == 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you know the count so why don't you just do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    listViewLossCount.Items.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 0]).SubItems.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 1]);
}
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rowsViewLossCount.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    listViewLossCount.Items.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 0]).SubItems.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a multi-dimensional array you need to ask for the length of each dimension separately:

GetLength(0) gives the first dimension and GetLength(1) gets the second. Your loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsViewLossCount.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    listViewLossCount.Items.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 0]).SubItems.Add(rowsViewLossCount[i, 1]);
}
```